What means by "a hyperbolic measure has product structure"
I try to figure out what means by "a hyperbolic measure has product structure".In the Anosov system,Lebesgue measure has local product structure with respect to the Lebesgure measure on stable and unstable manifold,this was shown by (transverse)absolute continuity of stable or unstable foliations.So,I wonder in the general case,for example,usually a nonuniform hyperbolic system with a hyperbolic measure $\mu$ ,literature says that it has product structure with respect to "projection measure" on unstable and stable manifold,but I wonder if absolute continuity of unstable/stable foliation is used in this case,and what's the relation between "projection measure" and Lebesgue measure on stable/unstable manifold.
Besides,I also want to figure out in the SRB measure case(disintegration with respect to unstable leave is abs to Lebesgue),it has local product with respect to which 2 measures?Product of "projection measure" with   Lebesgue measure on unstable leave?
